# MongoEngine Unexpectantly Changing Field Value

Tags: mongoengine

I am trying to simulate a sequence in a mongoengine document class. I have overwritten the **init** function to find the next contiguous value and am setting it in the document. For some reason the number gets incremented every time I add another object or call the objects.all() function. Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Here is the code:

```
from mongoengine import connect, Document, StringField, IntField

class MyDocument(Document):
    number = IntField(unique=True, required=True)
    name = StringField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDocument, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        num_objs = MyDocument.objects.count()
        self.number = 1 if num_objs == 0 else num_objs + 1

connect('test-database')
MyDocument.drop_collection()

pj = MyDocument(name='foo').save()
print((pj.number, pj.name))  # pj.number is 1?
print([(pj.number, pj.name) for pj in MyDocument.objects.all()]) # pj.number is 2?
pj = MyDocument(name='bar').save()
print([(pj.number, pj.name) for pj in MyDocument.objects.all()]) # both pj.numbers are 3?
```

which outputs:

```
(1, 'foo')
[(2, 'foo')]
[(3, 'foo'), (3, 'bar')]
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, using: Windows 10, Python 3.7.1, mongoengine 0.18.2, and mongodb server 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what the problem was that caused the side-effect, but I was able to fix it using a pre_save signal:

```
from mongoengine import connect, signals, Document, StringField, IntField

class MyDocument(Document):
    number = IntField(unique=True, required=True)
    name = StringField()

    @classmethod
    def pre_save(cls, sender, document, **kwargs):
        num_objs = MyDocument.objects.count()
        document.number = 1 if num_objs == 0 else num_objs + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoEngine provides a [SequenceField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.SequenceField) to support that use case. It should fit your need.

As to why your implementation is not correct, its because the constructor is called every time a new object is constructed as in

`MyDocument(name='whatever')`

But the constructor is also called everytime an object is fetched from the database, (e.g `MyDocument.objects.all()` or MyDocument.objects.first()) in fact behind the scenes, pymongo provides a dict that MongoEngine turns into a `MyDocument` instance by using the constructor.